# Motherboard GPU Limit

Tags: windows, graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, pci-express

Is there any limit on the number of `GPU`'s we can connect to a `motherboard`?
I'm not talking physically, which depends on the number or `PCI-E` slots available.

Please consider the following example:

A [motherboard](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-P/) has **6** `PCI-E` slots and I've [**6x3** `PCI-E` splitters](http://www.ebay.ie/itm/PCI-E-1X-Expansion-Kit-1-to-3-Ports-Switch-Multiplier-Hub-Riser-Card-USB-Cable-/232348928788?hash=item3619134b14:g:nnAAAOSwuMZZJvb-), which allows me to connect **3** `GPU` to 1 `PCI-E`, this makes a total number of **18** `GPU`'s.

Is this possible or will the motherboard have some physical limitations to it?
If so, how can we check this limit on the [motherboard specs](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z270-P/specifications/)?

Comment: How much bandwidth does one GPU require?  x1, x4, or x16 and what generation of PCI-e is the GPU ?

Comment: x1, this is a project for crypto currency minning. The Graphic board specifications state: "*PCI Express® 2.0 or higher version*" - http://www.sapphiretech.com/productdetial.asp?pid=2B6C8A0B-D4CD-4D0E-9878-2C2AC737F2CF&lang=eng

Comment: So 40 would be the limit, outside of power, requirements

Comment: @Ramhound Could you please explain me how you arrived to number 40? If you could post an answer it would be great.